# In the file path what does ".\\" , "/" , "\\" mean?

Tags: java

.\src/test/resources\ObjectRepository\config.properties

This is the file path I found in a project shared by my friend. I'm new to programming, so I don't understand what the symbols mean in the file path.

Comment: `.` means the current directory. `/` means going inside a child directory. It's `\` in Windows. But `\` is a special character in programming and it's used to define escape characters. So, we need to escape it with anther `\`, resulting `\\`. But you can safely use `/` and it should work on either of the platforms, but no guarantee though.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix-like operating systems, slash / is the separator in the 'pathname' of a file.  So '/foo/bar' means the file 'bar' which is found in the directory 'foo'.

On Windows, the reverse slash \ is used for the same purpose. Though many Windows routines will understand both forms.

Use of reverse slash is made more complicated in some programming languages because those languages use \ as an 'escape' character with special meaning.  To get a single literal \ you need to write \ \ (space added for clarity here).

Answer (score 1):

. is the current directory.

In Windows the path separator is the backslash .
But in literal strings in Java code you have to escape it with another backslash. (The same for Tab \t, e.g.)

But you can use the normal slash (the path separator in Unix/Linux) interchangeably.

So the path is: `./src/test/resources/ObjectRepository/config.properties`

Answer (score 1):

- `.` means it's the current directory
- `/` is normally used in paths to show the structure of files and folders
- `\\` is referring to `\` (used double because `\` is a special character)
  which is same as / but used differently depending on the OS